# jquery slider plugin suggestions - need 1 slider to fade and trigger the other to rotate

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, slider

I'm looking to have 1 big image slider at the top of my page with 4 related, smaller images below it.  when the top image changes (via fade effect), i want the bottom 4 to move like a carousel to the next 4.  the large image has no navigation, but clicking on the carousel next button should trigger a change in the big slide.  so, i'm wondering if there is a slider plugin that will let me have 2 sliders w/ different effects, but stay in sync.

some sliders i have looked at:
Nivo - 'before' and 'after change' callbacks, but no external controls
Anything slider - external control, but no 'on slide change' callback
Orbit slider - 'after change' callback, but no external control

by external controls i don't mean the nav buttons that the plugin generates.... i mean being able to bind an event (probably a click) to a random element to advance the slider to the next slide.

any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not totally sure about staying in sync, but the [jQuery cycle plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/) may get you there. It is very robust, has lots of effects, and callback functions (e.g. before, after). It *also* allows you to either attach navigation to links, or to *create* pagination links as well.

As for staying in sync, I think you will have to rely heavily on the callback functions upon interaction. It'd be pretty easy to get the to sets of images to rotate together on load:

```
$('#big_image_div, #little_images_ul').cycle({
    //options go here
});
```

You could also split the cycle declarations up:

```
$('#big_image_div').cycle({
    //options go here
});

$('#little_images_ul').cycle({
    //similar options go here
});
```

If you want to see all the [options, go here](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/options.html).

If you need them to be in sync, make sure the `timeout` option matches. You will have to fiddle with the options and callback functions to get the exact effect you want.

This isn't a complete answer, but it should get you going in the right direction.

Comment: yes it very much does.  thanks! cycle looks like it might be the solution finally.

Comment: additionally, i don't see an onChange callback... there is before and after.  i'm not missing it am i? (meaning a callback that fires during the transition?)

Comment: i'm not sure if it does, actually - i don't know if it's built that way. if you messed with things like setTimeout you could make a before function *seem* like it's firing during the transition.